# entity framework filter child collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these classes:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
    {
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public int TaskOwnerId { get; set; }
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
        public virtual List<TaskAssigned> TaskAssigns { get; set; }
        public virtual List<TaskComment> TaskComments { get; set; }
    }

public class TaskAssigned
    {
        public int TaskAssignedId { get; set; }
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

and I need to take all projects belong to each user based on tasks assigned to him/her
I have come up with this solution but I could not move forward:

```
public List<Project> GetProjectsByAccountIdUserId(int accountId, int userId)
        {
            var tasks = context.TaskAssigns.Where(ta => ta.UserId == userId).ToList();
            var projects =context.Projects.Where(p => p.AccountId == accountId).Include("Tasks").ToList();
            return projects;
        }
```

I do not know how to correlate and filter tasks for each project by taskId.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 context.Projects.Where( 
            p => p.Tasks.Any( 
                        t => t.TaskAssigns.Any( ta => ta.UserId == userId ) 
                        ) 
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing this type of task you want to correlate the data to who owns what.

So a project has tasks.  A user has tasks assigned to them.  A user is on a project.

So for a given user I want their projects.  Right? (you are nodding your head now)  But initially I only know the tasks from a users point of view and the tasks have knowledge of the project the user is on.

```
   var projectIdentities = (from t in context.Tasks 
                join a in context.TaskAssigned on t.TaskId equals a.TaskId
                where a.UserId == userId
                select t.ProjectId).Distinct();
   List<Project> userProjects = (from p in context.Projects
                     where projectIdentities.Contains(p.ProjectId)
                     select p).ToList();
   return userProjects;
```